# Что делает запрос?

Tags: delphi, sql

```
procedure TForm1.upperClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DM.Q1.Close;
 DM.Q1.SQL.Clear;
 DM.Q1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Sodinvois');
 DM.Q1.SQL.Add('WHERE UPPER(NAME)=UPPER(:PY)');
 DM.Q1.Prepare;
 DM.Q1.ParamByName('py').AsString:=edit.Text;
 dm.Q1.Open;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Выводит из таблицы  Sodinvois те записи, где `NAME=edit.Text`

Да и проверяет, переводя в верхний регистр (UPPER)

Answer (score 0):

Перевод в верхний регистр для условия 
"слово"="СЛОво", без этого "слово"<>"СЛОво".

p.s. сделайте что-нибудь с капчой.

Answer (score 0):

Это делаеться чтобы поле-значения проверялись, независимо от регистра.То есть считаеться что Маша,МАША,маша,мАША - все одинаковые слова так как upper("мАшА")="МАША".